# type hint for generic attribute inside abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, type-hinting

I have a convoluted problem with types that I can´t solve.

Let's say I have some abstract classes and a generic type equivalent to this

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Action(ABC):
    pass

ActionTypeVar = TypeVar("ActionTypeVar", bound="Action")

class Agent(ABC, Generic[ActionTypeVar]):
    actions: tuple[ActionTypeVar, ...]

    def get_action() -> ActionTypeVar:
       return self.action[0]
```

This works as intended. But I need is to define a function similar to get_action outside the class(in a different package in fact).

```py
def get_action_outside_class(agent: Agent) -> ActionTypeVar:
    return agent.actions[0]
```

The problem is that here the return type is not precise anymore, since we are outside the scope of the class. I wanted to indicate this is of the same type as the elements of `agent.actions`.

I have tried referencing the elements of `Agent.actions` in the return of `get_action` but I can't find out a proper way to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the function to access the internal details of the `Agent` instance, instead of simply using `Agent.get_action`?

Comment: that was just as an example. In practice there is no function `Agent.get_action` method

Comment: There probably should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `Agent` generically.

```
def get_action_outside_class(agent: Agent[ActionTypeVar]) -> ActionTypeVar:
    return agent.actions[0]
```

(Any `TypeVar` would do; it doesn't need to be the same one you used when defining `Agent`.)